# How make div not scrolling, fixed and keeps there width base on parent container

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have page that contains three elements: a header, an article, and a aside.
I want the scroll to only affect the article, and I’d like the header and aside to stay fixed.

I can make header fixed by using `position: fixed;` and it works.

But when I do the same to aside, its width swaps from being 30% of the width of the container to 30% of the browser width.

So I need the aside to be fixed (not scroll), but at the same time have a width of 30% of its container.

Snippet below, [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/DohaHamdan/ucnyowqj/2/)

```css
.body-header {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}

.body-content {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

aside {
  width: 30%;
  background: black;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="body-header">
    header
  </header>
  <div class="body-content">
    <article>
      <h1>Introduction t ththth tht</h1>
      <p>Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse risus, lacinia sit amet aliquet sit amet, ultricies nec ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque vestibulum facilisis. Curabitur hendrerit a libero id ullamcorper. Nam scelerisque felis non nunc tempus fringilla. Proin ullamcorper, massa vitae elementum aliquam, lectus velit imperdiet mauris, nec blandit justo leo ut nisl. Etiam sollicitudin, urna eget malesuada convallis, augue nunc molestie erat, fringilla fringilla augue purus ac lacus. Donec sagittis nisl quis rhoncus fermentum. Sed a velit sem. Suspendisse tempor tempus dolor, ac porta velit porta at. Integer mi est, commodo non aliquam et, venenatis id felis.Sed venenatis diam est, ut volutpat nisl laoreet sed. Sed ut quam sed nibh pharetra congue. Donec ullamcorper, arcu vel finibus dictum, urna purus congue libero, quis fringilla erat ante maximus mauris. Suspendisse odio sem, mollis ac mauris non, viverra bibendum elit. Phasellus malesuada augue nulla, vitae eleifend sapien vehicula et. Aliquam pharetra imperdiet mauris non scelerisque. Donec dictum fringilla ante ac accumsan. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut id tempus nisi, ut aliquet justo. Duis a pretium ligula. Morbi facilisis urna sed lacus feugiat, nec laoreet purus fermentum. Proin semper nisi nec sapien porta, quis dapibus tellus auctor Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus.</p>
    </article>
    <aside>
      g
    </aside>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't ignore the rules of SO - links to js fiddle must be accompanied by code in the question itself, commenting the link as code does not count and is really annoying as it means you cannot even click the link

Comment: Hi @Jala, you want article to be scrolled not aside right??

Comment: Seems `position:fixed` in `.aside`, works as you mentioned..

Comment: what is your html structure and applied css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want `aside` to be 30% of `body-content` which is also a percentage?

With a bit of maths, you can do the following:

You want 30% of 60%, which works out at 18%.

`60 divided by (10/3) = 18`

So change your `aside` to this (add `position: fixed` and change width to `width: 18%`):

```
aside {
  width: 18%;
  background: black;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 45px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

And you will have the result you wanted.

```css
.body-header {
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}

.body-content {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

aside {
  width: 18%;
  background: black;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 45px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="body-header">
    header
  </header>
  <div class="body-content">
    <article>
      <h1>Introduction t ththth tht</h1>
      <p>Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse risus, lacinia sit amet aliquet sit amet, ultricies nec ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque vestibulum facilisis. Curabitur hendrerit a libero id ullamcorper. Nam scelerisque felis non nunc tempus fringilla. Proin ullamcorper, massa vitae elementum aliquam, lectus velit imperdiet mauris, nec blandit justo leo ut nisl. Etiam sollicitudin, urna eget malesuada convallis, augue nunc molestie erat, fringilla fringilla augue purus ac lacus. Donec sagittis nisl quis rhoncus fermentum. Sed a velit sem. Suspendisse tempor tempus dolor, ac porta velit porta at. Integer mi est, commodo non aliquam et, venenatis id felis.Sed venenatis diam est, ut volutpat nisl laoreet sed. Sed ut quam sed nibh pharetra congue. Donec ullamcorper, arcu vel finibus dictum, urna purus congue libero, quis fringilla erat ante maximus mauris. Suspendisse odio sem, mollis ac mauris non, viverra bibendum elit. Phasellus malesuada augue nulla, vitae eleifend sapien vehicula et. Aliquam pharetra imperdiet mauris non scelerisque. Donec dictum fringilla ante ac accumsan. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut id tempus nisi, ut aliquet justo. Duis a pretium ligula. Morbi facilisis urna sed lacus feugiat, nec laoreet purus fermentum. Proin semper nisi nec sapien porta, quis dapibus tellus auctor Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus, Etiam non nulla id risus finibus laoreet. Vestibulum vel placerat quam. Suspendisse lacus risus.</p>
    </article>
    <aside>
      g
    </aside>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd think the easiest way to achieve this would be to use some JavaScript.

Using the example code below should do the trick:

```
var aside = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0],
    parent = document.getElementsByClassName("body-content")[0];

aside.style.width = ((parent.offsetWidth / 10) * 3) + "px";
```

Using this code and having the position set to fixed should give the desired effect.